# How to properly import .pdb into Blender?

Tags: blender

Recently, I need to make some molecular models in Blender. I try to use ChemOffice to get .pdb document and import it into Blender. **However**, when I load some simple .pdb document into Blender, things goes strangely. **What I see in the Blender is greatly different from what I've seen in ChemOffice.**[You can see a demonstration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq6Xb.jpg)(I try to make an ethane model, but I failed. It seems there are some more spheres in the pictures.)

What should I do to properly import .pdb file into Blender?

My final goal is to import Blender model into Unity3D.

Comment: Looks close, mostly a size issue, have you tried adjusting the import options, there are options for radius and scaling factor. Does [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/43468/935) offer any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everyone. After one more morning's research, I've found a great video that perfectly resolve my problem. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GbDkqw0U9Y) In fact, the problem comes from the design of the importation of Blender, which uses "duplivert" technique to build the model.

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching the pdb file into pymol (there is a free version). Make it a cartoon or spheres or sticks or whatever you want it to be.  Save image as VRML2 onto  your computer.  Import .wrl model into blender.  It will import as multiple meshes, you will need to control j all these meshes then put into edit mode and remove doubles.  You will also have a lot of materials.  You can recolor if you want by removing material slots then adding new materials, but it is time consuming. Not the best, but it does work.